# Horizontal Scrollbar not appearing in DataGrid

Tags: wpf, datagrid, scrollbar

My DataGrid appears with Data outside the visual scope. I have looked into several similar questions on StackOverflow but none of them seemed to solve my problem. I am not able to figure out as to what am I doing wrong. This is what my xaml looks like:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>        
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Foreground="{DynamicResource TitleFontColor}" 
     TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding WindowTitle}" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
     Margin="10,10,0,10" FontSize="18.667" FontFamily="Segoe UI" />
    <Border  Background="{DynamicResource pnlworkarea}" 
      Grid.Row="1" CornerRadius="2" BorderThickness="1">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="65"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Border BorderThickness="1" 
         Background="{DynamicResource Brush_HeaderNew}" 
         BorderBrush="{DynamicResource pnlworkareastroke}" 
         CornerRadius="2" Margin="5">
        <Grid Margin="0">
               <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ViewMenuItems}" SelectedItem="{Binding Viewselected}" 
                VerticalAlignment="Center" Style="{DynamicResource Content_Header_ListBoxStyle}" 
        ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource Header_DataTemplate}" 
        ItemContainerStyle="{DynamicResource ContentHeader_ListBoxItemStyle}"               
        ItemsPanel="{DynamicResource Header_ItemsPanelTemplate}" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>                                   
    </Grid>
    </Border>
    <Grid Grid.Row="1" Margin="5">
            <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10,0,0,0">
                     <ContentControl Focusable="False" Content="ContentControl"  
        Background="{DynamicResource Brush_VectorIcon}" 
       Template="{DynamicResource vector_Summary}" 
       Height="16" Margin="0,5,0,0"/>
        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding SearchDisplayMessage}" Margin="5,3,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
        <Grid Grid.Row="2" Margin="5">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <DataGrid  x:Name="dataGrid"
                    commands:ControlEvents.GridViewSelectionChangedEventCommand="{Binding SelectionItemsChangeCommand}"
                    SelectionMode="Single"
                    AutoGenerateColumns="True"                      
                    Margin="0,5" Grid.Row="1" IsReadOnly="True"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding GridItem, Mode=TwoWay}"  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}"
                    AlternatingRowBackground="#FFF5F4F8" Background="White" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                    ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" 
                    ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
                    ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                        <Behaviors:SelectorDoubleClickCommandBehavior Command="{Binding GridDoubleclickcommand}"/>
                    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>

                </DataGrid>
            </Grid>

        </Grid>

    </Border>

</Grid>
```

Just to add that the DataGrid here is not the actual DataGrid I am using. My Custom DataGrid is derived from DataGrid. But I have tried this with the normal DataGrid as well but doesn't seem to work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a height of Auto

```
<Grid Grid.Row="2" Margin="5">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <DataGrid  x:Name="dataGrid"
                    SelectionMode="Single"
                    AutoGenerateColumns="True"                      
                    Margin="0,5" Grid.Row="1" IsReadOnly="True"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding GridItem, Mode=TwoWay}"  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}"
                    AlternatingRowBackground="#FFF5F4F8" Background="White" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                    ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" 
                    ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
                    ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                </DataGrid>
            </Grid>
```

Change to

```
<DataGrid Grid.Row="2"  x:Name="dataGrid"
                    SelectionMode="Single"
                    AutoGenerateColumns="True"                      
                    Margin="0,5" Grid.Row="1" IsReadOnly="True"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding GridItem, Mode=TwoWay}"  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}"
                    AlternatingRowBackground="#FFF5F4F8" Background="White" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                    ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" 
                    ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
                    ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                </DataGrid>
```

Comment: I did as suggested but the Scrollbar seems to be not appearing even if I set it to Visible. I have even tried to put the DataGrid inside a ScrollViewer but in that case the DataGrid stretches beyond imagination. I don't mind using the DataGrid inside a ScrollViewer if there is a way to limit the width of the columns of the DataGrid allowing each column to stretch to the max value of the data that it contains.

Comment: "The" Scrollbar - which?  I don't follow.  Can you reproduce the problem in small code sample?

Comment: I have set the ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible". But that doesn't help. I am really short on time. So, as a workaround, I have put the datagrid in a ScrollViewer and on loaded event of the DataGrid, I am resizing the columns based on the content size in each. Now, the issue seems to be that I need to set the MinWidth for each column else they shrink too much if there is little data.

Comment: Again reproduce the problem with data and post it.

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar issue with the horizontal scrollbar not showing. I had a column with a width of "*". Once I removed this the scrollbar appeared. I guess if you set the width to a fixed with it would also appear.

Comment: This worked for me (I actually changed it from * to "Auto", though).  I believe the scrollbar automatically shows if a field runs *off the grid*, however if the column is sized to the exact size of the grid, it doesn't technically run off the grid / trigger the scrollbar to show.

Answer (score 2):

Here few things you should keep in mind assign width property od datagrid view. define your columns give width of the last column as auto and also assign some minWidth.

```
            <DataGrid  VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,0,0,0" Height="221" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="234"
                DataContext="{DynamicResource ItemCollectionViewSource}" 
                        ItemsSource="{Binding}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="True" 
                        ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" 
                        ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                        ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" >
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding ID}" Header="ID"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding URL}" Header="URL" Width="Auto" MinWidth="186"/>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
```

Comment: MinWidth is the key otherwise the grid will try very hard to shrink down columns to avoid scrolling horizontally

Answer (score 1):

I cant guess what you are doing wrong as the most scaled dopwn version of your code is showing horizontal scroll bar to me...

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <x:ArrayExtension x:Key="MyArray" Type="{x:Type TextBlock}">
        <TextBlock Name="Test1" Text="12345678"
                   DataContext="12345678" Tag="12345689"/>
        <TextBlock Name="Test2" Text="12345678"
                   DataContext="12345678" Tag="12345689"/>
        <TextBlock Name="Test1" Text="12345678"
                   DataContext="12345678" Tag="12345689"/>
        <TextBlock Name="Test2" Text="12345678"
                   DataContext="12345678" Tag="12345689"/>
        <TextBlock Name="Test1" Text="12345678"
                   DataContext="12345678" Tag="12345689"/>
        <TextBlock Name="Test2" Text="12345678"
                   DataContext="12345678" Tag="12345689"/>
        <TextBlock Name="Test1" Text="12345678"
                   DataContext="12345678" Tag="12345689"/>
        <TextBlock Name="Test2" Text="12345678"
                   DataContext="12345678" Tag="12345689"/>
        <TextBlock Name="Test1" Text="12345678"
                   DataContext="12345678" Tag="12345689"/>
        <TextBlock Name="Test2" Text="12345678"
                   DataContext="12345678" Tag="12345689"/>
        <TextBlock Name="Test1" Text="12345678"
                   DataContext="12345678" Tag="12345689"/>
        <TextBlock Name="Test2" Text="12345678"
                   DataContext="12345678" Tag="12345689"/>            
    </x:ArrayExtension>
</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left"
               TextWrapping="Wrap"
               Text="My Text Clock"
               VerticalAlignment="Center" 
               Margin="10,10,0,10" FontSize="18.667"
               FontFamily="Segoe UI" />
    <Border Grid.Row="1" CornerRadius="2" BorderThickness="1">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="65"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Border BorderThickness="1" 
                 CornerRadius="2" Margin="5">
                <Grid Margin="0">
                       <ListBox
                           ItemsSource="{Binding
                                ViewMenuItems}"                            
                           VerticalAlignment="Center"
                           HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>             
    </Grid>
    </Border>
    <Grid Grid.Row="1" Margin="5">
             <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                         Orientation="Horizontal"
                         VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10,0,0,0">
                    <ContentControl Focusable="False"
                                    Content="ContentControl"  
                                    Height="16" Margin="0,5,0,0"/>
                     <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap"
                                Text="DisplayHerePlz!"
                                Margin="5,3,0,0"
                                VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
              </StackPanel>
     </Grid>
         <Grid Grid.Row="2" Margin="5">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
             <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                  <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
             </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <tk:DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid"
            SelectionMode="Single"
       AutoGenerateColumns="True"   
               Margin="0,5" Grid.Row="1"
            IsReadOnly="True"   
            ItemsSource="{StaticResource MyArray}"
            ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" 
            ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
            ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
       AlternatingRowBackground="#FFF5F4F8" 
            Background="White"
            Grid.ColumnSpan="2">                        
      </tk:DataGrid>
    </Grid>
   </Grid>
  </Border>
</Grid>
```

Its probably the other bits that I have omitted which could be causing the horizontal width to stretch beyond scroll view...

Comment: Thanks for putting in the effort. Just wanted to know if there was anything obvious that I was missing. I am not able to figure out trying different solutions as to what seems to be the issue.